# AFNetworking unauthorized 401 error in iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, ios8, afnetworking

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];;

manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"application/json"];


[manager POST:url
   parameters:parameter
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

          NSLog(@"Response JSON: %@", data);


      } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
          NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

      }];
```

Above code is working fine in iOS7 but I got follow error code in ios8.

status code: 401, headers

```
"Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Mon, 10 Nov 2014 09:22:04 GMT";
Server = "nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)";
"Set-Cookie" = "request_method=POST; path=/";
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
"X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
"X-Frame-Options" = SAMEORIGIN;
"X-Request-Id" = "971366a5-f11d-4f3c-8a0f-0618905d43f4";
"X-Runtime" = "0.003365";
"X-XSS-Protection" = "1; mode=block";
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Im getting the same error with similar code.  Did you get anything yet?  What does the URL look like?  Im using GET and my URL looks like https://api.parse.com/1/classes/MyObjectClass?where=%7B%22updatedAt%22%3A%7B%22%24gte%22%3A%7B%22__type%22%3A%22Date%22%2C%22iso%22%3A%222014-11-15T02%3A13%3A44.999Z%22%7D%7D%7D